# Okta Python SDK - how to use the 'query' attribute in UsersClient get_users method

Tags: python, okta

I would like to use the `get_users(self, limit=None, query=None, filter_string=None):` method provided by `UsersClient.py` in the Python SDK and I intend to use the `query` and `filter_string` method parameters. However, there is no documentation regarding the same. I did try different ways of using them but to no avail. It would be great if you kindly throw some light on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `query` param takes a string that is matched against [firstName, lastName, or email](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#find-users).

```
client.get_users(query='sample@user.com')
```

The `filter_string` param takes a string in the format described [here](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#list-users-with-a-filter).

```
client.get_users(filter_string='profile.email eq "email@example.com"')
```

These two params can be used independently, but not together.